# Getting correct div class text without reloading page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I quickly put together a small piece of code to fetch and modify a string from a class on a webpage (chrome extension).
The code works Fine on the first runtime, but if I navigate the webpage to a new company where the class text is changing, the code stops to work correctly (it returns the values from the first runtime)

If I refresh the page or open it up in a new tab it works fine again.

I am 100% new to javascript, I have no clue how to fix this.

Sidenote: Is there a way for me to ask the user a boolean question on runtime, and depending on the answer return either the partname or the finalpart string to the clipboard?

```
// content.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.message === "clicked_browser_action") {
            var wholeName = document.getElementsByClassName('ng-binding ng-scope')[0].innerHTML;
            var partName = wholeName.substring(0, 4)
            var finalPart = "m" + partName.substring(0, 1) + "a" + partName.substring(2, 1) + "x" + partName.substring(3, 2) + "X" + partName.substring(3, 4)

            copyStringToClipboard(finalPart);
        }
    }
);

function copyStringToClipboard(str) {
    // Create new element
    var el = document.createElement('textarea');
    // Set value (string to be copied)
    el.value = str;
    // Set non-editable to avoid focus and move outside of view
    el.setAttribute('readonly', '');
    el.style = { position: 'absolute', left: '-9999px' };
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    // Select text inside element
    el.select();
    // Copy text to clipboard
    document.execCommand('copy');
    // Remove temporary element
    document.body.removeChild(el);
}
```

[image: Image of the Class]

Comment: It means the site is storing the values in internal DOM properties without exposing them into HTML. Without seeing the actual page or a relevant HTML excerpt thereof, I can only blindly guess: try using using `value` instead of `innerHTML`.

Comment: I added a picture of the source code. I tried to replace it with value but it didn't recieve the text (0007 in the picture). I will try later today or tomorrow to find a solution with your description of the problem as a helper :)

Comment: Is this the initial state (on the first run)? If so, add another image of the alternate state.

Comment: Yes it is. I do not know what happened, my code is exactly the same but now it works 100% of the time. I am sorry for bothering, But I can't replicate the issue anymore. Thanks for your time comitment.

Comment: Can you add any details like error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.